# How to find resolution of digital sensor

Tags: image-processing

The image sensor of a particular digital camera contains
2016 × 3024 pixels. The geometry of this sensor is identical to
that of a traditional 35mm camera (with an image size of 24 × 36
mm) except that it is 1.6 times smaller. Compute the resolution of
this digital sensor in dpi

Answer (score 0):

this looks like pure math question how it is related to programing?

**DPI** is dot per inch, inch is `2.54mm` so you divide resolution in dots (pixels) by size of chip in inches.

chip size is:

```
(24 × 36)/1.6 mm 
(24 × 36)/(1.6*2.54) inch
(24 × 36)/(4.064) inch
```

The **DPI** is then

```
(2016 × 3024) / [(24 × 36)/(4.064)]
(2016/24 × 3024/36) * (4.064)
(84 × 84) * (4.064)
(341.376 x 341.376) DPI
```

So the camera pixel density is `341.376` **DPI**